# Asus WL-520GC + external HDD via Ethernet

Tags: backup, router, storage, network-attached-storage, ethernet

Has anyone experience of using such combination? Exactly with the same model (or from same model line).

*How does it works? How hard is to set up all that? What difficulties?*

I use this router a couple of years, but now i haven't such external drive at my disposal.

I want to buy something like [Verbatim 47591](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Verbatim-47591-1TB-Gigabit-NAS/dp/B002OEBNHE) or [Western Digital WDH1NC10000](http://www.geek.com/articles/chips/review-western-digital-my-book-world-edition-1tb-nas-20090218/).

(By the way, my router has no USB ports, therefore only Ethernet-ports for external HDD are supported.)

Thanks you a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Asus WL-520GC has 4 Ethernet ports so if you have at least one free, you will have absolutely **no problems** connecting a Net Disk.

Similar combination (with a ZyXEL NSA-210) worked for me without problems.

Just connect the router to the Net Disk and you will see your disk in the network. You should also connect to it via it's web interface (all of them have it) and configure its settings.